# past simple with today

Tags: past-tense

I have seen this sentence: "He did not go to sleep late yesterday because he (wants/ wanted) to go fishing today."

I think wanted is better because the idea of going fishing was planned yesterday but I am not sure  because today is a mark of present

Comment: I think you are right. "He wants to go fishing today" implies that he hasn't gone yet. Presumably the reason for going to bed early yesterday was to get up early today, so (unless the speaker was up even earlier) he is probably fishing now.

Comment: It's primarily a stylistic choice whether to "backshift" his (currently-held) wishes. But as @KateBunting points out, ***if** he has **already** gone fishing at time of utterance*, you ***must*** backshift, or it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say "wanted". If he went to bed early last night, presumably he had a reason for doing this last night. The desire to do this was in the past. If he didn't want to go fishing until now, that could not have affected what he did last night.

Using the present tense wouldn't necessarily be wrong. One could say that the desire existed yesterday but it still exists today, so the desire is in the present.

When he goes fishing -- whether in the past or the present -- is irrelevant to the correct tense of the verb "want" here. "Want" does not describe when he did or will go fishing, but when he had the desire to go to bed early. If I write, "Yesterday I wanted to go fishing next week", "wanted" is properly in the past tense because the desire was in the past. The fact that the fishing trip is in the future is irrelevant.